# How do I add the catalog/navigation block or am I just lost?

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation, static-block, permissions

I am working on Magento 1.9.2.4 using a Porto theme. I am trying to get my sub category listing block working so it shows the sub category on the parent category page. The links are showing and working but no images. I read a previous thread to add the catalog/navigation block under permissions and allow it. But I don't even show is in my list of available blocks. What am I missing? :(

http://market.matthewsenvironmentalsolutions.com/index.php/cremator-parts.html

[image: Screenshot of missing images]

Thank you so much - any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: share your code for that block and check the media permission ones.